# Php empty not working using POST

Tags: php

I made one form with some data that is entering into sql, and a little php script for not allowing empty values in some fields. There is no any problem in code, but it is still allowing to leave blank fields.
EDIT: When I leave fname blank field, it is still submitting data into the table. I don;t want to send any data if any of field is empty.
Code:
`prviposalji.php`

```
    <body>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
echo "Morate uneti ime";
}
if (empty($_POST['city'])) {
echo "Morate uneti grad";
}
}

?>


<div class="unos">
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<div class="floatleft">Ime:</div> <div class="floatright"><input type="text" name="fname" /></div><br><br>
<div class="floatleft">Grad:</div><div class="floatright"><input type="text" name="city" /></div><br><br>
<div class="floatleft">Okrug:</div><div class="floatright"><input type="text" name="county" /></div><br><br>
<div class="floatleft">Telefon:</div><div class="floatright"><input type="text" name="phone" /></div><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji podatke" /> <input type="reset" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

`insert.php`

```
<body>

<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mobilni");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$ime = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fname']);
$grad = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['city']);
$okrug = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['county']);
$telefon = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone']);
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO imena (Ime, Grad, Okrug, Telefon) VALUES ('$ime', '$grad', '$okrug', '$telefon')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Podaci su prosleđeni administratoru. Nakon odobravanja, Vaš oglas će se pojaviti. Hvala na poverenju.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
```

Comment: You could use `if ($_POST) { ... }` instead of `if ($_POST['submit']) { ... }` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your originally posted question, and before you posted your DB-related code:

- **https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27888250/1**

It doesn't work because of your initial conditional statement

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

where your submit button doesn't hold the name attribute of "submit".

Rename it to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji podatke" />
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is an example, since you've not posted full code.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
        // echo "name empty";
        die("Name empty.");
        }


        else{
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        echo "First name: " . $fname . "<br>";
        }

if (empty($_POST['city'])) {
// echo "city empty";
die("City empty");
}

        else{
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        echo "City: " . $city . "<br>";
        }


} // brace for if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

Comment: @Stefan Worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried your edited code for at least 3 times, still not working. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Stefan You're going to have to define "Not working". This doesn't help me, help you. What are your expected results?

Comment: When I enter all data, and leave City field blank and press submit, data is entered into SQL. I don't want to let data with blank fields being entered in table.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, so now the plot thickens. Why didn't you post that in the first place? Just add a die() or exit() after each failed post. I gave an answer on what you posted, so I answered the original question, not code that doesn't exist, least not in what you posted.

Comment: Please, give me example.

Comment: @Stefan Reload under **Edit**. You can then modify to suit.

Comment: I copied this code and still not working. I really don't know what can be problem. And this really matters to me.

Comment: @Stefan You posted: *"Still not working, and I edited name of button to "submit". I really don't know what is problem here."* in another answer given yet you accepted mine. If something doesn't work, then post another question with your full code. As far as I'm concerned, this question has been answered, as per your original post.

Comment: @Stefan You need to move your PHP out from your form and inside "insert.php" and wrap the code you want to "execute", inside that whole conditional statement. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // execute something } else{ // do something else }`. Otherwise and on how you have it now, you will be best using Ajax, but that is an entirely new topic.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
echo "Morate uneti ime";
}
if (empty($_POST['city'])) {
echo "Morate uneti grad";
}
}

?>
```

> The **name attribute** is missing in your submit button, be sure to add this, then this will work for you!

**EDIT**
or try this way

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['submit']))
{echo "Bad request";}
elseif (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
echo "Morate uneti ime";
if (empty($_POST['city'])) {
echo "Morate uneti grad";
}
else
{//update the data}

?>
```

**Not tested**

> if you are still having issues, check out This tutorial on [How to validate a form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp)

Comment: Still not working, and I edited name of button to "submit". I really don't know what is problem here.

Comment: @AmitThakur As far as I'm concerned, the question has been answered and OP should be posting a new question in that regard. Not edit a question a half hour later.

Comment: I can see that you have marked an answer, it means The answer worked for you, and you still have issues!..wy?